# TextView Invisibility

Tags: android, xml, textview, visible

I have a textView in which i have set the color as transparent in xml

```
android:background="#ffffff"
```

Now i have written the code to change the image of the textView onClick

```
t1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fslash);
```

but it does not seem to do anything onClick of the textView.

Please help

Comment: #FFFFFF means white not transparent. And more code please.

Comment: It works fine. Did you actually click on the text and check it

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement click method like this

```
 textview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            try {
                                // Your Code
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                            }

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
t1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

private void onClick(View v){

TextView txt=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtid);
txt.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fslash); 
}

});
```

Comment: is this the same..??

`t2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                       
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View v) {
                                       
                                        t2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fslash);
                                                                   
                                       }
                               });`

Answer (score 0):

try setting:

```
android:clickable="true"
```

**or**

you can also do in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <android:background="@drawable/yourimg" />
</item>
<item android:background="#000000" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Comment: save this xml suppose "bkg.xml" and give your texviews background=bkg
complete!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on the TextView, you have to set the clickable attribute to true. Otherwise it will not listen to any click! You can do that in code or in the xml file:

Code:

`t1.setClickable(true);`

XML:

`android:clickable="true"`